# rdelrosario.push notification nuget is not working on the newest XF/Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've used rdelrosario.push notification nuget on the previous version of my app. (XF 2.3.3)

I've been making a new update.
But I realized that I can't get push token on Android. when I try 
CrossPushNotification.Initialize("XXXXXX");
OnRegistered method is not hit.

It was working fine. But I'm not sure since when this is broken.
We're about to release a new update but just found this critical problem.

Is there anyone having same problem with me?
I made an issue on the github.
https://github.com/rdelrosario/xamarin-plugins/issues/122

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem thanksfully.

I removed Xamarin.Googleplay.Measurement, which is out of date.
and update Xamarin.Googleplayservices.basement to 42.1001

got it working.